# How can I track time my app is visible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, statistics

I am developing an ipad app and i would like to track how much time users are using my app.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at an analytics package such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).

You can also use [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mark it as helpful, i got excited by flurry. very helpful